# nginx статистика или запуск скрипта при скачивании определенного файла

Tags: php, nginx

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы если запросили определенный файл. После его выдачи. nginx запустил скрипт с именем этого файла. вобщем есть несколько имен файлов. надо по ним статистику вести. сколько раз скачали.

1й вариант я вижу просматривать лог. с какой то периодичностью. раз в 10-30 минут

2й вариант перенаправлять запрос php а он отдает этот файл. а я уже там пишу статистику

может есть какой то еще вариант? хороший вариант был бы с каким то callback. файл скачан запустили сценарий

Comment: `nginx post_action` какой-то гуглится

Comment: Анализ логов самый простой и прямой как палка вариант. Если нет каких-то особенных требований, то лучше на нём и остановиться.

Comment: в отдельный файл логи тогда писать для этих файлов

Comment: поразбираюсь с post_action  - вроде то что надо

Comment: если в бизнес-требованиях нет необходимости в мгновенной статистике, то использование логов будет лучше чем post_action т.к. при каждом запросе не нужно делать какие-то действия типа обновление счетчика в БД

Answer (score 1):

Используйте логирование.

1. создайте кастомный формат лога директивой:

```
http {
...
   log_format counter '$time_local $request';
...
}
```

2. Создайте location, в который попадали бы нужные файлы и добавьте логирование. Например:

```
location = /image.jpeg {
   access_log /var/log/image_requests.log counter flush=30s;
}
```

3. дальше этот лог можно обработать башскриптом, который посчитает кол-во запросов каждого файла:

```
cat /var/log/image_requests.log | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | sort | uniq -c
```

Если нужны агрегированные данные по дням, месяцам или секундам, то для этого в логе добавил дату.

Comment: а как организовать запуск баш скрипта? крон каждые сколько ?
Просто мне как раз надо, чтобы сразу же информация была и обновляла запись в базе. типо сейчас дата. скачан этот файл. чтоб потом можно было посчитать сколько за день

Comment: кроном можно, период запуска сделайте максимально возможным исходя из требований

Comment: чет странность какая то указываю лог другое имя файла. он создается но пустой. ничего не пишет туда access_log /var/log/test.log combined; имею ввиду для отдельного файла

Comment: следом за именем файла у меня идет имя формата лога. У меня он называется ```counter```.

Comment: опция flush=30s означает, что запись будет производится раз в 30 сек